# Print the number of vowels in the text entered in input

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function count() {
  var para = document.getElementById("myInput");
  var result = document.getElementById("result");

  if (para.value === "") {
    alert("Enter text!");
  } else {
    var str = para.value;
    var c = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      str[i] = str[i].toLowerCase();
      if (str[i] === 'a' || str[i] === 'e' || str[i] === 'i' || str[i] === 'o' || str[i] === 'u') {
        c++;
      }
    }

    result.innerHTML = "The number of vowels = " + c;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'helvetica';
  text-align: center;
  background-color: cadetblue;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 40px;
}

#container {
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-right: 50%;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #505050;
}

#header {
  padding: 30px 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

#header:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

input {
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 75%;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 0.1px solid #ddd;
  border-right: none;
}

#myBtn {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  opacity: 0.8;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 0.1px solid #ddd;
  border-left: none;
}

#myBtn:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

#result {
  padding-left: 40px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Vowel Counter</h1>

<div id="container">

  <div id="header">

    <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Enter text...">
    <button onclick="count()" id="myBtn">Go</button>

  </div>

  <p id="result"></p>

</div>
```

The text is entered in the input and when the button is clicked, I want the number of vowels to be displayed in the paragraph by changing its innerHTML. Where am I going wrong? I want to use javascript only. I tried doing it by taking a string and checking each of its character. If it is a vowel then increment the value of c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the p#result to be display none here.

```
#result {
  display: none;
  padding-left: 40px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

You need to change the style to display: block once the user clicks on the button.

```
result.style.display= 'block';
```

```html
<html>

    <head>
    
        <title>Vowel Counter</title>
    
        <link type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Commissioner&family=Montserrat&family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        
        <style type="text/css">
        
            body
            {
                font-family: 'helvetica';
                text-align: center;
                background-color: cadetblue;
            }
            
            *
            {
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            
            h1
            {
                color: white;
                margin-top: 50px;
                font-family: 'Montserrat';
                font-size: 40px;
            }
            
            #container
            {
                width: 50%;
                margin-top: 50px;
                margin-left: 25%;
                margin-right: 50%;
                background-color: #f5f5f5;
                border-radius: 10px;
                box-shadow: 0 0 10px #505050;
            }
            
            #header
            {
                
                padding: 30px 40px;
                text-align: center;
            }
            
            #header:after
            {
                content: "";
                display: table;
                clear: both;
            }
            
            input
            {
                margin: 0;
                border-radius: 0;
                width: 75%;
                padding: 10px;
                float: left;
                font-size: 16px;
                border: 0.1px solid #ddd;
                border-right: none;
            }
            
            #myBtn 
            {
                padding: 10px;
                width: 25%;
                background-color: cadetblue;
                opacity: 0.8;
                color: white;
                float: left;
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 16px;
                cursor: pointer;
                transition: 0.3s;
                border-radius: 0;
                border: 0.1px solid #ddd;
                border-left: none;
            }

            #myBtn:hover 
            {
              opacity: 1;
            }
            
            #result
            {
                display: none;
                padding-left: 40px;
                text-align: left;
                font-size: 25px;
            }
        
        </style>
        
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
        <h1>Vowel Counter</h1>
        
        <div id="container">
        
            <div id="header">
            
                <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Enter text...">
                <button onclick="count()" id="myBtn">Go</button>
                
            </div>
            
            <p id="result"></p>
            
        </div>
        
        <script type="text/javascript">
        
            function count()
            {
                var para = document.getElementById("myInput");
                var result = document.getElementById("result");
                
                if(para.value === "")
                {
                    alert("Enter text!");
                }
                else
                {
                    var str = para.value;
                    var c = 0;
                    for(var i=0; i<str.length; i++)
                    {
                        str[i] = str[i].toLowerCase();
                        if(str[i] === 'a' || str[i] === 'e' || str[i] === 'i' || str[i] === 'o' || str[i] === 'u')
                        {
                            c++;
                        }
                    }
                    
                    result.innerHTML = "The number of vowels = " + c;
                    result.style.display= 'block';
                }
            }
            
        </script>
    
    </body>
    
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works. This is your mistake :

```
#result {
  display: none;
}
```

Fix :

```
result.style.display = "block";
```

Also you can count the vowels with a regex :

```
const vowelsCount = "some string with vowels".match(/a|e|i|o|u/ig).length
```

Answer (score 1):

As @sabbir mentioned you need to change the style of paragraph to make it visible to show the result. Along with that your can also improve the count method using javascript regex like below. In this regex we are only match the vowels from the given string and will return an array contains all the vowels and then you can count the length of array which only contains the vowels.

```
function count() {
    var para = document.getElementById("myInput");
    var result = document.getElementById("result");

    if (para.value === "") {
        alert("Enter text!");
    } else {
        var str = para.value.match(/[aeiou]/g);
        result.innerHTML = "The number of vowels = " + str.length;
        result.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```